# Reduce downtime when restarting google speech recognition for keyword detection

Tags: android, speech-recognition, android-sensors

I am attempting to implement keyword detection using the android speech recognition API.
I have achieved this so far by calling recognizer.startListening, and when the onError or onResults functions are called, cancelling the recognizer and then starting it again.

```
speech.cancel();
speech.startListening(recognizerIntent);
```

This is working pretty well, however I have a little downtime between cancelling and restarting (0.5 - 1 second) and I wonder if there was either a better and less "hacky" way of getting this functionality, or just a way to ensure the recognizer restarts quicker.

Here's some LogCat Info that may be useful?

```
11-25 09:49:03.331: I/MainActivity(4730): onError
11-25 09:49:03.361: I/GoogleRecognitionServiceImpl(4745): #startListening [en-GB]
11-25 09:49:03.371: D/AudioHardware(104): AudioHardware pcm capture is going to standby.
11-25 09:49:03.391: D/dalvikvm(4745): threadid=35: thread exiting, not yet detached (count=0)
11-25 09:49:03.391: D/dalvikvm(4745): threadid=36: thread exiting, not yet detached (count=0)
11-25 09:49:03.391: I/AudioService(386):  AudioFocus  abandonAudioFocus() from android.media.AudioManager@417d3b30fiw@4172a1f8
11-25 09:49:03.391: I/AudioService(386):  AudioFocus  abandonAudioFocus() from android.media.AudioManager@417d3b30fiw@4172a1f8
11-25 09:49:03.421: I/decoder(4745): WARNING: score_cache_ref not set. Using deprecated score cache creation.
11-25 09:49:03.431: D/dalvikvm(4745): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 555K, 28% free 3248K/4476K, paused 24ms, total 24ms
11-25 09:49:03.441: I/MicrophoneInputStream(4745): mic_starting ela@4174c4a8
11-25 09:49:03.451: I/decoder(4745): WARNING: score_cache_ref not set. Using deprecated score cache creation.
11-25 09:49:03.461: D/AudioHardware(104): AudioHardware pcm playback is exiting standby.
11-25 09:49:03.461: D/AudioHardware(104): openPcmOut_l() mPcmOpenCnt: 0
11-25 09:49:03.461: D/alsa_pcm(104): pcm_open(0x0003f000)
11-25 09:49:03.461: D/alsa_pcm(104): pcm_open() period sz multiplier 16
11-25 09:49:03.461: D/alsa_pcm(104): pcm_open() period cnt 6
11-25 09:49:03.461: D/alsa_pcm(104): pcm_open() period_cnt 6 period_sz 1024 channels 2
11-25 09:49:03.461: D/AudioHardware(104): AudioStreamInALSA::setParameters() input_source=6;routing=262144
11-25 09:49:03.471: D/AudioHardware(104): AudioHardware pcm capture is exiting standby.
11-25 09:49:03.471: D/alsa_pcm(104): pcm_open(0x1003f000)
11-25 09:49:03.471: D/alsa_pcm(104): pcm_open() period sz multiplier 16
11-25 09:49:03.471: D/alsa_pcm(104): pcm_open() period cnt 6
11-25 09:49:03.481: D/dalvikvm(4745): GC_CONCURRENT freed 27K, 17% free 3720K/4476K, paused 3ms+2ms, total 33ms
11-25 09:49:03.481: D/alsa_pcm(104): pcm_open() period_cnt 6 period_sz 1024 channels 2
11-25 09:49:03.581: I/alsa_pcm(104): leftValid 1 rightValid 2
11-25 09:49:03.821: W/SpeechLevelGenerator(4745): Really low audio levels detected. The audio input may have issues.
11-25 09:49:03.821: I/MainActivity(4730): onReadyForSpeech
```

It appears to me that the issue *may* lie in the microphone hardware side of things, as I am somewhat new to android I am not well versed in this area.

Thanks in advance to any response.